# Instance a variable declared in the header file without default constructor

Tags: c++

I've just started to learn C++ using Visual Studio 2019.

I'm trying to move the variable declaration from a class method to the header file. Originally, this is my class:

The header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
 
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

    ~MyClass();

    bool Connect(std::string host, std::string port);
};
```

And the `Cpp` file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "TelnetClient.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

bool MyClass::Connect(std::string host, std::string port)
{
    // Omitted for brevety

    // Create a Telnet client
    TelnetClient telnet(io_service, iterator);

    // Omitted for brevety
}
```

But, this version doesn't compile (here, I have moved `telnet` declaration to the header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class TelnetClient;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

    ~MyClass();

    bool Connect(std::string host, std::string port);

private:
    TelnetClient telnet;
};
```

And the `Cpp` file:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "TelnetClient.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

bool MyClass::Connect(std::string host, std::string port)
{
    // Omitted for brevety

    // Create a Telnet client
    telnet(io_service, iterator);

    // Omitted for brevety
}
```

With this new version, I get two errors.

One, in the new header file:

> telnet uses class 'TelnetClient' undefined.

And another one, inside the `Cpp` file:

> error C2064: the term is not evaluated as a function with 2 arguments

I have checked [Constructors and member initializer lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), and they don't say how can I do it.

How can I instance the `telnet` variable declared in the header file?

**UPDATE:**

I have updated the header file, removing the forward declaration and adding the `#include "TelnetClient.h"` and, in the method, changed this:

```
telnet = TelnetClient(io_service, iterator);
```

And now I get two new error messages.

One, in the `MyClass` constructor:

> error C2512 'TelnetClient': no suitable default constructor available

And the second one in the new `telnet = TelnetClient(...`:

> error C2280 'TelnetClient & TelnetClient :: operator = (const
> TelnetClient &)': Attempting to reference a removed function.

Comment: You'll need to move `#include "TelnetClient.h"` into your `MyClass` header file.

Comment: `telnet(io_service, iterator);` probably needs to be something like `telnet = TelnetClient(io_service, iterator);`

Comment: `host` and `port` vs `io_service` and `iterator`? Are those typos or are they unrelated variables?

Comment: Do you have access to `io_service` and `iterator` in `MyClass`'s constructor?  The constructor is the appropriate place to construct instance variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `.h` file, the compiler doesn't know what the `TelnetClient` type looks like, as you are only *forward declaring* it, so you can't declare any instances of `TelnetClient` in your header, only `TelnetClient*` pointers and `TelnetClient&` references. You would need to move the `#include "TelnetClient.h"` statement from your `.cpp` file into your `.h` file, and get rid of the forward declaration.

Then, inside of your `Connect()` method, you are still trying to call the `TelnetClient`'s constructor direct on the `telnet` member, which won't work in that context anymore. But, you can create a new instance and move it into the existing instance.

For example:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "TelnetClient.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

    ~MyClass();

    bool Connect(std::string host, std::string port);

private:
    TelnetClient telnet;
};
```

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

bool MyClass::Connect(std::string host, std::string port)
{
    // Omitted for brevety

    // Create a Telnet client
    telnet = TelnetClient(io_service, iterator);

    // Omitted for brevety
}
```

**UPDATE:** Actually, this won't work in your case, because this error:

> error C2512 'TelnetClient': no suitable default constructor available

means `TelnetClient` does not have a parameter-less default constructor, so you can't construct a `TelnetClient` object without passing parameters into its constructor. Which means if you intend to declare a `TelnetClient` instance in your `.h` file then you must use your `MyClass` constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to construct it with parameters.  Also, because this error:

> error C2280 'TelnetClient & TelnetClient :: operator = (const TelnetClient &)': Attempting to reference a removed function.

means that `TelnetClient` has disabled its copy assignment operator, and doesn't have a move assignment operator, so `telnet = TelnetClient(io_service, iterator)` will not work, either.

For example:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include "TelnetClient.h"

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

    ~MyClass();

    bool Connect(std::string host, std::string port);

private:
    TelnetClient telnet;
};
```

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

MyClass::MyClass()
    : telnet(io_service, iterator) // <-- you will have to get these params from somewhere, or pass them in to MyClass() itself
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
}

bool MyClass::Connect(std::string host, std::string port)
{
    // Omitted for brevety
}
```

Otherwise, you will have to change the `telnet` member to be a `TelnetClient*` pointer instead, then you can continue using your forward declaration in the `.h` file, and your `Connect()` method can `new` a `TelnetClient` object using its 2-parameter constructor.  But then you will have to update `MyClass` to follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) to manage that pointer correctly to avoid leaks and such.

For example:

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <string>

class TelnetClient;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
    MyClass(const MyClass &) = delete;

    ~MyClass();

    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass &) = delete;

    bool Connect(std::string host, std::string port);

private:
    TelnetClient* telnet;
};
```

```cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "TelnetClient.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

MyClass::MyClass()
    : telnet(NULL)
{
}

MyClass::~MyClass()
{
    delete telnet;
}

bool MyClass::Connect(std::string host, std::string port)
{
    // Omitted for brevety

    // Create a Telnet client
    delete telnet;
    telnet = new TelnetClient(io_service, iterator);

    // Omitted for brevety
}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks. How can I move it into the existing instance?

Answer (score 1):

A forward declaration is not sufficient to declare a member variable. The definition of `TelnetClient` must be available. Remove the forward declaration and include `"TelnetClient.h"` in the header.

Members are initialized by the constructor not in arbitrary methods (actually before the constructor runs). When you want to assign a new instance to the member you need to use its `operator=` (provided it has one) to assign a new instance:

```
bool MyClass::Connect(std::string host, std::string port)
{
    // Omitted for brevety

    // Create a new Telnet client
    telnet = TelnetClient(io_service, iterator);

    // Omitted for brevety
}
```

However, if possible you should properly construct the member in the contructor already:

```
MyClass::MyClass(io_service_t io_service, iterator_t iterator) : telnet(io_service,iterator)
{
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code with your suggestion and there are new messages errors.

Comment: @VansFannel then you can open a new question :)